# How to convert string to numpy array and display the image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, opencv, python

**How to convert String with 3d array to numpy array and display the image?**

**Script:**

```
import numpy as np

# client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# client.connect(('localhost', 6060))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    opt = input()
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if opt == 'x': break

    print(frame)
    # client.send(bytes(str(frame), 'utf-8'))
    print('done!')

frame = str(frame)
frame_ = np.array(frame)

cv2.imshow('frame', frame_)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Error:**

```
  File "/Users/homepro/PycharmProject/Projects/Socket/videocallApp/client.py", line 22, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame_)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - mat data type = 19 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/homepro/PycharmProject/Projects/Socket/videocallApp/client.py", line 22, in 
cv2.imshow('frame', frame_)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - mat data type = 19 is not supported
> - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'

Comment: Instead of converting to string, convert to bytes array: `frame = frame.tobytes()`, Converting back looks like: `frame_ = (np.frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8).reshape([height, width, 3]))`. I think you can convert from bytes array to string using `frame.decode("utf-8")`, and from string to bytes using `frame_.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: I still get error : 
frame_ = np.frombuffer(frameBin, np.uint8).reshape([720, 1280, 3])
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2764965 into shape (720,1280,3)

Comment: The array size in bytes should be `720*1280*3` = `2764800`. You have `165` extra bytes. I can't tell why.

Comment: I get the error even after lowering the resolution
Error: 
  File "/Users/homepro/PycharmProject/Projects/Socket/videocallApp/client.py", line 28, in <module>
    frame_ = np.frombuffer(frameBin, np.uint8).reshape([480, 640, 3])
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 921765 into shape (480,640,3)

Comment: `480*640*3` = `921600`, and you have `921765`. I can't help you if you don't post your updated code. You know you can edit your question, right?

Comment: WHAT cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) and cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) says ?

Comment: does removing frame = str(frame) and frame_ = np.array(frame) and leaving just 

cv2.imshow('frame', frame) works ?